# Rewrite SQL Select to use $wpdb->prepare

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to rewrite an SQL select query to use the `$wpdb->prepare` function. My original SQL query looks like this and works fine.

```
function hfwp_SaveFormData($formData, $userID, $today, $dbTable) {
   global $wpdb;

   $wpdb->show_errors();
   $query = "SELECT UserID FROM $dbTable WHERE Date = '$today' AND UserID = '$userID'";
   $wpdb->get_results( $query );
   $count = $wpdb->num_rows;

   if ($count > 0) {
      $wpdb->update($dbTable, array('Distance' => $formData), array('Date' => $today, 'UserID' => $userID));
   }else{
      $wpdb->insert($dbTable, array('UserID' => $userID, 'Date' => $today, 'Distance' => $formData));
   }
}
```

I then tried to rewrite the `SELECT` statement to use `$wpdb->prepare`:

```
$wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT UserID FROM %s WHERE Date = %s AND UserID = %d", $dbTable, $today, $userID ) );
```

But it gives an error in the log but not enough to give me a hint on what is wrong.

I also tried another version of the `$wpdb->prepare`:

```
$query = "SELECT UserID FROM %s WHERE Date = %s AND UserID = %d";
$prepared = $wpdb->prepare( $query , $dbTable, $today, $userID );
$wpdb->get_results( $prepared );
```

Comment: Just because because the error message didn't give YOU a hint on what is wrong doesn't mean you should ommit it from the question, it's a really important part of your question. In fact, if you would have added the error message, you would have gotten the answer in about 27 seconds (26 of these to write the answer), because it would contain something like `"SELECT UserID FROM 'yourtablename' WHERE Date = ...` which tells us: You cannot use a prepared tablename. So instead use `"SELECT UserID FROM $dbTable WHERE Date = %s AND UserID = %d"` with 2 parameters.

Comment: Okay my mistake, I'll remember that.

And thank you for the help.